# TypeScript/EsLint: BufferEncoding is not defined while I have @types/node installed?

Tags: typescript, types, eslint

Why is BufferEnconding undefined with @types/node installed? I don't see any option from intelliSense to auto-import it either.

[image]

[image]

Also no exports from "node:buffer".

```
import type { BufferEncoding } from 'node:buffer';
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay found a solution: add BufferEncoding to globals.

```
{
  "globals": {
         "BufferEncoding": "readonly"
  }
}
```

If someone has a better solution than explicitly adding types from @types/node to `.eslintrc.json` globals I would love to hear about it.